# Vim: how to highlight brackets for functions

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to define a vim highlighting scheme where the brackets belonging to language functions are highlighted the same as functions, so for example if functions are red then their brackets will also be red. My idea is this will differentiate them from other round-bracket constructions. (Maybe this is actually a terrible idea, but I wanted to try it out.)

I tried defining a region like this:

```
syn region Function matchgroup=Function start=+Abcd\s*(+ end=+)+ contains=ALL
```

However this never finds its closing bracket.

Following the suggestion below (thanks!) I changed it to:

```
hi Function gui=bold guifg=Red guibg=NONE
syn region SpecialFunc matchgroup=Function start=+Abcd\s*(+ end=+)+ contains=ALL keepend

if 0
Abcd(123)
Abcd(Xxxx(123))
endif
```

(Save the above as a .vim file, open it in Vim and `:so %` to test.)

I now get this:

[image: Screenshot showing nested brackets are not preserved]

Answer (score 0):

To get your closing bracket in your example highlighted, you can try

```
hi Functionmine gui=bold guifg=Red guibg=NONE

syn region Functionmine matchgroup=Function start=+TestFun\s*(+ end=+)$+ contains=ALL keepend
```

---

Another try:

```
hi Function gui=bold guifg=Red guibg=NONE
hi InsideFunction gui=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE
syn match Function "Abcd(.*)" contains=InsideFunction
syn match InsideFunction "(\zs.*\ze)"

if 0
Abcd(123)
Abcd(Xxxx(123))
endif
```

Comment: That seems to do it - thanks! (Now to do this for 300+ other functions...)

Comment: Sorry, turns out it doesn't. My functions don't end at the end of a line, but without the "$" the end pattern matches the first closing bracket it comes to.

Comment: Nice try, thanks :) It's not really practical though, as it doesn't nest or span lines, and it suppresses all other groups within brackets. It looks like this isn't doable without shedloads of Vimscript.

Comment: I am sorry, I tried :-) Maybe it is possible, I just don't know how. Have you thought about using [rainbow parentheses](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim)?